# Sync data from reference URLs over iCloud?

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud

I want to sync documents from my documents directory over iCloud, but I want it to stay there if the user becomes disconnected from iCloud, and so I was wondering if it'd be possible to save reference URLs in iCloud, which would sync the original file and put it back in it's original position between devices?